# Can I manage dpkg-installed package with apt-get?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

At the very beginning after I set up my Ubuntu 12.04, I installed Webmin (`dpkg -s webmin` reports the version to be 1.610) by first downloading the .deb file with `wget` and then running `dpkg --install webmin_1.610_all.deb`, according to the [instructions](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html) on Webmin.

Later, I found that I prefer to use `apt-get` to manage as much packages as possible, so that I can manage them in a unified way. Is it possible (or does it make sense at all to ask in this way) to make apt-get to manage this Webmin package installed with `dpkg`?  I understand there is a APT repository and the latest version is 1.67. If so, how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not respiratory it's repository.

Comment: you want to upgrade a package via apt-get which was already installed by dpkg.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oops i've fixed the typo... thanks.  Yes that's what I mean, so you meant dpkg and apt-get are referring to the same thing? My original thought is that the .deb package have no information about path to the repository, therefore cannot upgrade itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short:** the answer to your question is just in the page you posted.

If you like to install and update Webmin via APT, edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file on your system and add the lines :

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

You should also fetch and install my GPG key with which the repository is signed, with the commands :

```
cd /root
wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
```

You will now be able to install with the commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

**Long version.** If the package was installed with `dpkg` then it is installed. Once installed `apt-get` can handle it, i.e. you may run `sudo apt-get remove webmin` to uninstall it, or `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the dependencies.

Just to be clear, `apt-get` **USES** `dpkg`. In a very short simplified way, dpkg is the engine behind apt-get (and aptitude), it's the guy leading with the actual installation of packages directly and, of course, is potentially harmful to your system if you mess up, whilst `apt-get` really takes care of you trying to avoid any disturbance that `dpkg` may generate. :)

Going to the point, the first part of my answer reply to you directly, the alternative to install a .deb with `dpkg` is to add a repository. Why, well in the repository you will catch every update of the program, while with `dpkg` your version is fixed. Also, in theory, the repo may solve all your dependencies automatically. In dpkg is allways convenient check for broken packages afeter the installation with `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Adding a repo consist on four steps: add the address of the software source, add the key to make ubuntu able to trust the source, update the database, and install. All of them are above. Adding a ppa saves you the steps 1 and 2! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive and easy-to-understand answer! You made me understand the relation between `dpkg` and `apt-get` now.